# Faceted search using MS SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm looking at options for providing Faceted Search functionality, admittedly not a specialty of mine. From what I understand, I think that this should be achievable quite nicely by using cubes in SSAS (another none-specialty of mine). Would this be a good direction to head? Is SSAS itself a good framework to use for adding support of faceted search to an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) / [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Lucene is a full-text indexer and Solr is a full-text search server which has a facet search functionality built-in.

SSAS is a ok, but it's targeting some other usage scenarios. It is possible to employ it but you will have to implement faceting manually (though you will stay within platform boundaries as Solr is Java-based).